# Strange register definition ,declaration and usage

Tags: c, struct, unions, cpu-registers

I'm working on GTM module and  have trouve to understand an MCAL code , 
here is the code sample :

```
/* Here the definition of the register */
/** \brief  CMU Global Clock Control Numerator Register */
typedef struct _Ifx_GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM_Bits
{
    Ifx_Strict_32Bit GCLK_NUM:24;           /**< \brief [23:0] Numerator for global clock divider (rw) */
    Ifx_Strict_32Bit reserved_24:8;         /**< \brief \internal Reserved */
} Ifx_GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM_Bits;

/**
\brief  CMU Global Clock Control Numerator Register */
typedef union
{
    unsigned int U;                         /**< \brief Unsigned access */
    signed int I;                           /**< \brief Signed access */
    Ifx_GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM_Bits B;            /**< \brief Bitfield access */
} Ifx_GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM;

/*CMU Global Clock Control Numerator Register */
 #define GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM /*lint --e(923)*/ (*(volatile fx_GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM*)0xF0100304u)

/* Here we are using the register */
  /* The content of Numerator and Denominator are temporarily taken in local
     variables and used in the if statement below for Misra reasons. */
  RegTemp3 = GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM.U;
```

So why there are fileds U and I in the union and why U is used insteead of the bitfield Ifx_GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM_Bits B

I have a problem executing this code since I have an arithmetic overflow exception , when executing :

```
RegTemp3 = GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM.U;
```

Comment: How is RegTemp3 defined? unions are used to represent the same thing in different ways. So, they wanted to assign an 'unsigned' version of the union to the reg. It would prevent from sign extension in the Reg

Comment: Looks like C with a smattering of XML. Removed the C++ tag.

Comment: uint32 RegTemp3;          /* Temporary variable to store the register value */

Comment: What is the bit-size of int for your compiler?  In any case, to ensure type compatibility, RegTemp3 should be declared as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

`GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM` is a hardcoded hardware register specific to the target system.

Reading it into `RegTemp3` as an unsigned value is necessary to ensure a single access is made to the hardware as 32 bits.

Do you execute this code on the target system?

Are you sure there is support for `arithmetic overflow exception`?

If you are running the code on the host system, it most likely will cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The code is running on the `target system`.
Yes there is support for `overflow arithmetic exception`

For reading the register value , why the code is not using :

```
RegTemp3 = GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM.B;
```

instead of

```
RegTemp3 = GTM_CMU_GCLK_NUM.U;
```